# How to change the permission on a single file?

Tags: permissions, root

I need to change the permission on a couple of files in the `/usr/share/backgrounds/`. I've been lurking around forums but no one will give me a straight answer. Rather, they just keep warning me against it. 
The files in question are two images, lets say, `img1.jpg` and `img2.jpg`. All I want to do is set their "Other" permission from "None" to "Read-only".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
sudo chmod 444 /usr/share/backgrounds/img1.jpg
```

444 Allow read permission to owner, group and world.

Comment: `chmod` to 444 causes the file read-only to all users (owner, group and others), revoking all write permissions as well!

Answer (score 2):

Type in a terminal:

```
sudo chmod o+r /usr/share/backgrounds/img1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

as owner or user with write permissions on the file:

```
chmod o+r filename
```